# How to inject javascript into a web page loaded in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I need to load a web page from an independent website in my iOS app, however, the webpage is not optimized for mobile experience. I want to execute some js to re-layout the page after it is loaded.

1. Is this possible?
2. How shall I do it so that users don't see the original page, only the re-layouted version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way to inject your JS is using the following UIWebView method

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```